# How can I enable transparent compression on exisitng f2fs partition?

Tags: linux, filesystems, compression, mkfs, f2fs

As far as I know it is possible to enable on new partition. Is there any way to enable compression on existing f2fs partition? I don't want to wipe and create a new partition to enable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this has to be enabled upon creation. You will have to create a new partition and enable it by passing the `compression` option.

Comment: Can you provide, as requested, any authoritative source to back the claim?

Comment: As per the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/F2FS#Compression): "To use compression, include the `compression` option: `# mkfs.f2fs -l mylabel -O extra_attr,inode_checksum,sb_checksum,compression /dev/sdxY`".